# Rails migration file not adding all my defined columns to the db

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration, osx-snow-leopard, rake

I'm trying to create a rails app, but somethings going wrong, I'm getting a nasty error `undefined method`title' for #`

I've used this ling:

```
ruby script/generate scaffold Blog title:String body:text
```

to generate the following migration file:

```
class CreateBlogs < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
  create_table :blogs do |t|
    t.String :title
    t.text :body

    t.timestamps
  end
end

 def self.down
  drop_table :blogs
 end
end
```

Upon inspection of the database, there's no 'title' column. I've tried this with a few different names and for whatever reason, even though there's two columns along with the timestamps in the migration file, after I've run rake db:migrate there's only one field in addition to the timestamps and id. Not sure why my 'title' field isn't being created :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't string be a lowercase 'S'?